# How many different functions satisfy $f(\frac{ia}{2}) = \log(\frac{a}{2})-i\frac{3\pi}{2}$ on a region $G$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $G$ be the region$$G = \mathbb{C} - \{z\in\mathbb{C}: z = iy,|y|\geq a>0\}$$
where $y,a$ are real numbers. Then let $G'$ be the region $$G' = \{z: z\in G, \text{Im}(z)>0\}.$$

Suppose $f(z)$ is a branch of the logarithm in $G'$ such that $$f\bigg(\frac{ia}{2}\bigg) = \ln(a/2)-\frac{3}{2}i\pi.$$ How many functions are there that satisfy the same properties as $f$ on $G'$ (i.e. a branch of the logarithm with the same value at $ia\pi/2$)?

My attempt: I think there is only one such function, if there is another, say $g(z)$ then it differs from $f(z)$ by $2\pi k i$ since $G'$ is a region and both $f(z),g(z)$ are a branch of the logarithm on $G'$. But since $g(\frac{ia}{2})=f(\frac{ia}{2})$ we must have $k = 0$, i.e. $f\equiv g$.

Is this correct?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the used definition of "region". As you write "since $G'$ is a region", the definition you use probably includes connectedness, and then it's good. Otherwise, you'd need to add the word "connected" in a suitable place.

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes the definition I use for region is "open and connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$, thanks for the response!